# select top 10 records for each group in sql

Tags: sql-server

i have table below field

**Hour,PathId,Duration,Event,CellId,Channel**

Here each cellid have four pathId(i.e, 0,1,2,3),Each pathId have many Events,Channel and Durations.

Now i want to display top 10 records(each pathId) for each cellid.

(group by cellid, pathid and channel we got duration.. we take top ten each pathid based on duration)

i have 50+ cellid and each cellid have four pathid(i.e, 0,1,2,3)

pls help me

!
[SampleTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fnJF.png)

!
[outputtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy33c.png)

Comment: You'll find plenty of duplicates in google if you search your title, i just picked the first. -1

Answer (score 3):

> i want to display top 10 records(pathId) for each cellid.

You can use the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to do that, something like:

```
WITH Ranked
AS
(
   SELECT
     Hour,PathId,Duration,Event,CellId,Channel,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cellid ORDER BY pathId) AS RN
   FROM tablename
)
SELECT Hour,PathId,Duration,Event,CellId,Channel
FROM Ranked
WHERE RN <= 10
```

The function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cellid ORDER BY pathId)` will generate a ranking number, by ordering the `pathId` for each group of `cellid` and then get the top 10. (Note that this will order by `pathId` ascending).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66127/discussion-on-answer-by-mahmoud-gamal-select-top-10-records-for-each-group-in-sq).